# If A is a subset of B and B complement isn't empty,is $ P(A)$ larger or smaller than $P(A|B)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

I wanted to know if my reasoning is right for the question so here it goes. 
I said that $P(A)$ is smaller than $P(A|B)$ given that $P(A|B) = P(A \cap B)/ P(B)$ we see that the $P(B) > 0$ has to be greater than zero where $P(A)$ can be any number. Most of $A$ occurs in $B$ since $P(B)$ is greater by default more than $P(A)$.

Comment: @bod, you meant the complement of $B$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Sorry about that I'm new to this site I'll make sure to do that next time!

Answer (score 1):

More simply, you have $$ P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)} \ge P(A)$$ since $P(B)\le 1.$ The fact that $P(B)>0$ is necessary for $P(A|B)$ to even be defined so isn't worth hemming and hawing about (and it isn't really pertinent to the question). As bof said in the comments, in order to have strict inequality, what's important is that $P(B)<1,$ which means $B$'s complement has nonzero probability, not just that it's non-empty.

Comment: First off thank you for your detailed input, I appreciate that so much! , Secondly so basically it's already known that the probability of B has to be greater than zero which I knew was redundant to explain but to clarify that P(A) is larger correct? 

Comment: @BartholomewAllen Right, if you're trying to explain that you're not dividing by zero here (or that you're excluding $P(B)<0$). I guess after the inequality I wrote down I could have easily written "since $0<P(B)\le 1$" instead. The point I was making is that you didn't mention $P(B)\le 1$ which is more pertinent here, since it's necessary for the proof and $P(B)<1$ is necessary for $P(A \mid B)$ to be strictly larger.